# Joint distribution of column sums when row sums are fixed

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, joint-distribution

Suppose I have an $m$ by $n$ table $X_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$, where in each row, $r$ randomly chosen entries are set to 1 (the rest are 0), i.e. $\sum_j X_{ij}=r$.

I know that e.g. the column sum $\sum_i X_{i1} $ has a binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(m, r/n) $. But what is the joint distribution of all column sums, i.e. of $(\sum_i X_{i1},\; ...,\;\sum_i X_{in})$ ?

Comment: Can you write out the distribution of the whole matrix? What do you notice about the $n$th column sum given the rest?